How to load JSON and make it reactive in Nuxt 3
In my Nuxt 3 app I import the json file like this:
import data from "~/assets/videos/videos.json"

Logging data (console.log('data =', data);) provides me with the desired content over which I can loop.
However, being new to all this I believe to understand that I have to turn this data object into a reactive object in order to work with it comfortably. So I try to do this:
import data from "~/assets/videos/videos.json"
let videoList = ref(data)
console.log('videoList =', videoList.value)

But instead of a nicely formed object I get something like this:
videoList = Proxy(Object) {data: {…}}
  [[Handler]]:MutableReactiveHandler
    _isReadonly:false
    _isShallow:false
    [[Prototype]]:BaseReactiveHandler
  [[Target]]:Object
    data:{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}}
    [[Prototype]]:Object
  [[IsRevoked]]:false

This doesn't look right to me. What am I doing wrong here? (This is all on my local development environment so far, by the way.)
